# Как при нажатии на кнопку, поменять картинку в image используя только XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

Как при нажатии на кнопку, поменять картинку в image используя только XAML?
Задача стоит такая, как я могу при нажатии на кнопку, передать в image картинку, которая помещена у меня в кнопку? Вот код кнопки:

```
<Button Width="150"
        Height="150"
        Name="Male"
        Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <Image Source="/Resource/male-icon.png"/>
</Button>
```

Допустим я выбираю кнопку с изображением мужчины, в правом столбце стоит Image, картинка, которая стояла в кнопке, так же должна отобразиться в этом Image. По такой же аналогии должна работать кнопка с картинкой женщины.

[image: Окно программы]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, конечно.

Например, так:

```
<Border Padding="10" Margin="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray"
        Height="210" Width="210">
    <Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Source, ElementName=ImageChooser}"/>
</Border>
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ImageChooser" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <Image Source="Resources/male.png" Width="64" Margin="4"/>
    <Image Source="Resources/female.png" Width="64" Margin="4"/>
</ListBox>
```

Получается вот что:

[image: ну как же без картинки-то?]

Однако, я бы на вашем месте не увлекался выносом бизнес-логики в разметку, а честно создал бы VM-классы, и привязывался к ним.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ДмитрийПафос: Пожалуйста!